# Получить html сайта

Tags: html, golang, url

На Go написал функцию для того чтобы получать html сайтов по url:

```
func HTTPGet(url string, timeout time.Duration) (content []byte, err error) {
    if strings.Index(url, "www.") == -1 {
        url = strings.Replace(url, "http://", "http://www.", -1)
        url = strings.Replace(url, "https://", "https://www.", -1)
    }
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify:          true,
            PreferServerCipherSuites:    true,
            SessionTicketsDisabled:      true,
            DynamicRecordSizingDisabled: true,
        },
    }

    var netClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout:   timeout,
        Transport: tr,
    }
    response, err := netClient.Get(url)

    if response == nil {
        url = strings.Replace(url, "www.", "", -1)

        response, err = netClient.Get(url)

        if response == nil {
            return
        }
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    content, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    return
}
```

Большая часть сайтов отработала нормально, но есть сайты, которые, если в браузере руками вбивать, работают, но функция возвращает такие ошибки:

> Error URL https://hollisterco.com err:Get https://www.hollisterco.com:read tcp 192.168.0.107:63431->104.81.103.80:443: wsarecv: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> Error URL https://deepin.org err:Get https://www.deepin.org: 301
>   response missing Location header
>
> Error URL http://tdscpc.gov.in err:Get https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/: 302
>   response missing Location header
>
> Error URL https://alternate.de err:Get https://www.alternate.de: EOF

Как можно это поправить можно?

Comment: Сделать вторую попытку получения?

Comment: У меня получение идет в 2 этапа

Comment: Делайте две попытки этих двух этапов, чо

Comment: А смысл этого в чем?

Comment: В том, что при второй попытке ошибки может и не быть

Comment: Ничего не поменялось

Comment: Такая проблема не специфична для go или вашего кода. Я писал недавно программу на C# и столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Попробуйте почитать про html запросы и изучить все происходящие у вас запросы через программу fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Добавьте головы `User-Agent` как у какого-нибудь браузера и `Location`.